# how do I save changes made in Firefox Developement Edition

Tags: css, firefox, grid

As I am trying to figure out the 'CSS Grid', I stumbled over Firefox Developement Edition. By the way, a great tool for learning CSS Grid. It would be even nicer if I could use the editor to actually change stuff. Unfortunately, I do not know how to save the changes I made (img).
help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Style_Editor) you can save any changes you've made to the style sheet to your local computer by clicking the Save button in the bottom-right corner of each sheet's entry in the list.

Answer (score 4):

In modern Firefox, there is a new feature for this!

In the inspector, in the right pane, the fourth tab should be `Changes`.
It contains a button to `Copy All Changes` you made to the clipboard as a stylesheet.

You can then use the extension `Stylish`, create a new style in there, paste those styles into the text box, add a URL patten for which it should apply via the buttons below, give it a name, save the thing, and you’re set.

One caveat: If you *disabled* CSS rules on that page, they will appear as *comments* and do nothing. So you need to uncomment them, and set their value to something like `none` or `initial` or `unset`.
E.g. to force those brain-dead sites that are designed for tablets only to use the full width of your screen, you’d disable `max-width`, which would appear as `/* max-width: 80rem; */` or something in your styles. So you’d turn that into `max-width: none;`.

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot shows the Inspector-View of the dev tools. You can save files to you local disc with in the Style-Editor-View. There is a little save-button for each style-file.

[image]

However you also can mark style properties with the mouse and copy and paste them anywhere.

Comment: I think I will switch to english. the german translation didnt give me the insight there was actually an editor. however,.. thx a lot.